# Configure a DLINK AP to connect to 802.1x LAN

Tags: router, ethernet, ieee-802.1x

My hostel is in the process of implementing AAA using 802.1x, PEAP + MSCHAPv2 on Ethernet.

I have a DLINK 850L router, is it possible to configure it to connect to 802.1x? DD-WRT is not available for this (Realtek chipset).

I am not looking for exact instructions, rather the general direction I need to look at.

Comment: Configuring consumer network products is off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for what types of questions are on/off-topic.

Comment: you can ask about consumer gear over on [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Comment: pls delete and re-post there. Stack Exchange best-practice to migrate only if Q has answers or comments that need to be preserved.